Prevent XPO from generating SQL with too many parameters?
Our clients want to do a single query to a Person table that fetches the records whose integer ids are included in a large list, often thousands of ids at once, e.g.:
List<int> idsOfRecordsToRetrieve = (list of 5000 ids starting with 100, 205, 215);

List<Person> people = new XPQuery<Person>(session).Where(p => idsOfRecordsToRetrieve.Contains(p.Id).ToList();

A problem we have is that the SQL ends up being written like:
select ... from Person where id in (@p0, @p1, @p2 ... @p0 = 100, @p1 = 205, @p2 = 215 ...
But we hit the SQL Server parameter limit because it tries to create a parameter for every id
Is there some way to prevent it from making parameters like this and write out something more like
select ... from Person where id in (100, 205, 215 ...)
Within the limitations of our client's requirements and the system we're working with, it would be very hard to break up that query or find something else in common between all the records we want to query that uses up fewer parameters
For now, we are trying to migrate to other systems which allow us to generate better SQL (or at least have more control over how our SQL is generated), but there is pressure to come up with some immediate solution
I mean, sometimes there is no immediate solution, but I'm hoping there are some options out there

Convert your list into a TVP or JSON and use raw queries to get your data. I think newest EF core uses OPENJSON itself for such queries.

Ty, that will also be tricky for us for reasons that are sadly unrelated to actual quality coding, but if that's the recommended approach, it gives us more leverage
